# Mediation in lavaan with multiple DVs

Tags: r-lavaan

Trying to conduct a mediation analysis using lavaan. I have one IV, one mediator and multiple DVs (four).
Can someone help me with a code for this? I know the simple mediation code. Do I need to write 4 different codes or this can be managed in one and how?

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a simple modification of a single outcome mediation model.
Instead of estimating a*b1 only, you'd add three additional outcomes with paths (b2, b3, b4) between the mediator and each outcome. You'd also specify correlated residuals among all 4 outcomes. 
Indirect effects to specify are:

```
Indirect 1:= a*b1
Indirect 2:= a*b2
Indirect 3:= a*b3
Indirect 4:= a*b4
```